# How to define the models of a MongoDB database with document validation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, schema

### Context

I'm working on a project where I use MongoDB with JavaScript. It is [this FreeCodeCamp Voting App](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-voting-app). I think there must be a different -and easier- way to do it as I cannot find any examples of what I want to do. Or maybe how I'm trying to structure the database is bringing new problems.

For the database I want to use a model like this one:

```
Poll = {
  name: name, // string
  options: [
    {opt: optionName1, votes: number},
    {opt: optionName2, votes: number},
    //...
  ],
  createdBy: userName, // string
  dateCreated: date,
}
```

The only way I find to do this is using the `validator` option when I create a collection. Then I have created a seed.js file where I start the database. I'm doing the following:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');

mongo.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/votingapp')
.then((db) => {
  db.createCollection('polls', {
    validator: {$and: [
      {name: {$exists: true, $type: 'string'}},
      {options: {$exists: true, $type: 'array'}},
      {createdBy: {$exists: true, $type: 'string'}},
      {dateCreated: {$exists: true, $type: 'date'}},
    ]},
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error connecting to the DB for seeding.');
  console.log(err);
});
```

### Questions

How can I ensure that inside the array named "options" I am inserting objects with properties "opt" and "votes"? And how do I tell MongoDB that "opt" is a string and "votes" is a number?

Can I validate that the "userName" exists in a list of users stored in other collection?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav . This, in fact, solved my doubt. In this case, should I delete this question?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to delete, then you can.